# PHP Image Upload Resize, Watermark, Title & Copyright Info

Tags: image, image-processing, gd, image-upload

Ive written an image upload and resize script for my website which allows users to upload images, and then the script resizes the images in 3 different sizes and adds a watermark image (my website logo) on the top.

The problem I have is, that if a user then tries to upload one of the resized photos again, it will then add the logo watermark on top of it again.

What I want is to maybe add some information to the uploaded image (i.e. author, which I could set to my website name), so that if a user uploads an image which has already been watermarked, I can put a check in my script so that I dont add the watermark logo again.

Is this possible with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php